# I am trying to update my /etc/hosts file on my load balancer server using ansible so I created a jinja2 template and add my vars from ansible facts

Tags: jinja2

{"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'default_ipv4'"}
here is the error I keep running into.
[ansible playbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKR67.png)

[my jinja2 template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiVOo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue on your variables:

```
{{ hostvars[host].['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}
```

Try with ansible_default_ipv4

Comment: I tried that and it still was not working